# How do I format Registry->Shell->Open->Command (output from AssocQueryString)

Tags: c++, c, windows

I can't use ShellExecute(Ex) but I have to provide functionality very much like it.

My function accepts a "file" and "arguments" string.  From the file string I extract an extension (if available) and I call AssocQueryStringW.  Specifically:

```
    rc = AssocQueryStringW(URL_SCHEME_FILE | ASSOCF_NOTRUNCATE,
                           ASSOCSTR_COMMAND,
                           extension,
                           verb,
                           execStr,
                           &execStrSize);
```

(verb == "open").  If an extension has been registered this will return the data string associated with the registry entry: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/\Shell\Open\Command.  I thought I could use FormatMessage to format the returned string and my arguments.  Unfortunately, some entries contain (%*).  The IE.AssocFile.WEBSITE contains a %l (yes lowercase L, not one (1). I'm passing this information to CreateProcessAsUser.  Is there a windows function/API that will format these "command lines"?

If not can I depend on %* being the last test in the shell open string and that no other arguments but %1 (filename) are used?  In other words can I just replace the %* with my arguments string?

Comment: Can you explain, why you can't use `ShellExecuteEx`?

Comment: I need to execute in the security context of the thread rather than that of the process.

Comment: FYI, the new learn.microsoft.com is broken in many ways. We need to confirm everything read in the online docs directly in the SDK header files (e.g. um/Shlwapi.h). The `URL_SCHEME` enum is for [`ParseURL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-parseurlw). The value `URL_SCHEME_FILE` (9) is numerically equivalent to `ASSOCF_INIT_DEFAULTTOFOLDER | ASSOCF_INIT_NOREMAPCLSID`.

Comment: Use the flag `ASSOCF_INIT_UNKNOWN` to fail if there's no registered association, instead of getting the Windows 7+ "open with" program.

Comment: You can preprocess the template with [`SHEvaluateSystemCommandTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shevaluatesystemcommandtemplate), but it's not the full service routine that you're looking for. It more securely splits out the `lpApplicationName` and `lpCommandLine` parameters for use with `CreateProcess[AsUser]`. You'll still have to manually substitute arguments for the parameter inserts.

Comment: The target file -- as if the user double clicked on the file -- is `%1` (or `%l` or `%L`, a relic of the Windows 9x era that's functionally the same). Honor how this is used in the command line. The rest of the arguments get substituted as the `%*` string.